# Can you redirect a 403 to a 404 in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to redirect users that land on a 403 to a 404 instead. This is simply just an extra bit of protection from hackers so that it doesn't give away our file structure.

Is there a nice configuration i can do inside my web.xml?

Spring 4.3
Spring Security 4.2

Comment: In what way does responding with a 404 instead of a 403 provide "protection from hackers"? If you configure your authorization layer correctly, then non-existent resources within sub-paths requiring authentication would always produce a 403 for unauthenticated users, and only if they are authenticated would they receive a 404.

Comment: You can do it either way really, but a 403 kinda implies that "they might be something here if you can find a vulnerability" whereas a 404 implies "there's nothing here in any case" which _may_ cause an attacker not to bother looking further.

Comment: yup, exactly what @stevestorey said - just don't want to give any clues at all away so want them to think cool there is nothing here

Comment: you can write a controller advice for 403 error and return response entity of 404 I think

Answer (score -2):

You’re achieve this redirection by configuring web.xml file. You'll want to use the  element to map the 403 status code to a specific error page, which in turn will be redirected to the 404 error page. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
<web-app>
<!-- Other configurations -->

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/redirect-404</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404-error-page.jsp</location> <!-- Or your desired 404 page -->
</error-page>

<!-- Other configurations -->
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).